# Best practice of syntax highlighting in Blogger

Tags: php, syntax, highlighting, blogger

First question on here.
I'm writing a blog at http://mpgengine.blogspot.co.uk/ and I want to put command line code, MySQL and PHP snippets and also whole PHP scripts in my posts.

I've tried using some of the Javascript highlighting scripts from Google, but these seem to have unpredictable results.
I have several questions.
1. Is there a standard way in display code (maybe in those dot bordered boxes)
2. Can someone let me know why the JS is showing my code in different ways?
3. Is it possible to display entire PHP scripts on Blogger?

Comment: @jashwant - lol you're right.  Deleting my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

[Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). 
Its the most famous and reliable syntax highlighter and works for many languages (including php).

Also, here's the link to integrate it on blogger.

[Integrate syntax highlighter on blogger](http://www.cyberack.com/2007/07/adding-syntax-highlighter-to-blogger.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<pre class="brush: php"></pre>
```

It works well for me. I hope it helps you.